# How to create a model for this type of dataset

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science, artificial-intelligence

DataFrame:

|  | name | editor | delegator | writer | owner | financer | toppers | best_point_of_contact |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | newpaper1 | A | A | B | A,B | B | A,B,C | A |

Target Column : best_point_of_contact ( the user who should be contacted for updates )

Other Columns : Provide information that which user is performing which task ( for example A and B are the owners, and B is the writer )

Question : How should I refactor this dataset in order to create a model to determine the best point of contact given the other features?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess the most forward (and trivial) solution would be to represent each unique point of contact as a unique one-hot-vector, then you can map each column (feature) into its corresponding one-hot-vector representation. At the end, your new feature vector would be the concatenation of all the one-hot-vectors from every column.

Let `n_contacts` represent the number of unique points of contact we have in our data (3 in your case), and `n_columns` represent the number of columns we have for each sample in out data (6 in your case). Then, the resulting feature vector would be a `n_contacts * n_columns` dimensional vector (18 dimensional in your case).

Applying the above approach to your example would look something like this (assuming we have 3 unique  points of contact):

Map each point of contact into its corresponding one-hot-vector representation:

```
A = [1, 0, 0]
B = [0, 1, 0]
C = [0, 0, 1]
```

Map sample 0's columns into their one-hot-vector representations:

```
editor = [1, 0, 0]  # A
delegator = [1, 0, 0]  # A
writer = [0, 1, 0]  # B
owner = [1, 1, 0]  # A, B
financer = [0, 1, 0]  # B
toppers = [1, 1, 1]  # A, B, C
```

Your sample's target:

```
best_point_of_contact = [1, 0, 0]  # A
```

Finally, sample 0's mapped feature vector would be the concatenation of all the one-hot-vectors from its columns:

```
res = editor + delegator + writer + owner + financer + toppers
```

> res = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]